# BroadcastReceiver method onReceive() not called when broadcast is sent from IntentService

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

As the title says, I have an Activity which starts an IntentService. After the IntentService is done doing all its work, I want it to broadcast the result back to my Activity. However, when I do this the onReceive method of my BroadcastReceiver isn't called. I'm trying to follow this guide from the Android documentation: [Report Status From an IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html)

This is how everything is setup:

I have a class StatusReceiver which extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
    class StatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

Context mContext;

public StatusReceiver(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    boolean success;

    success = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", false);

    if(success)
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Profile picture updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Profile picture couldn't be updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

In my onCreate() of my Activity, I instantiate a StatusReceiver:

```
    //This broadcast receiver will receive the result of image uploads.
    statusReceiver = new StatusReceiver(getApplicationContext());
```

In my onResume I register the receiver:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //register the receiver
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(UserProfileSettings.this).registerReceiver(statusReceiver, new IntentFilter("result"));
}
```

In my onPause() I unregister the receiver:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //unregister receiver when activity is paused
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(UserProfileSettings.this).unregisterReceiver(statusReceiver);
}
```

Finally, in my IntentService after all the work is done I want to send the result back to the Activity. This method is called from within Firebase CompletionListener:

```
    /**
 * This method broadcasts the result of writing the user's new profile picture to Firebase.
 * @param success - boolean representing whether or not the write was successful.
 */
private void sendResult(final boolean success){

    Intent result = new Intent("result");
    result.putExtra("success", success);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(result);

}
```

The listener:

```
    mDatabase.getReference(Users.NODE_NAME).child(userId).child("avatar").setValue(imageUrl, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                //if we didn't encounter an error
                if(databaseError == null)
                    sendResult(true);
                else
                    sendResult(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is your activity resumed to receive the broadcast?

Comment: Have you checked the log if your firebase `onComplete` method is ever called?

Comment: @PotapovAnton yeah, the activity is resumed after everything is done.

Comment: @tingyik90 I haven't checked the log but I know the firebase operation is successful because I've placed a checkpoint within the onComplete method and it runs. Also, I can see the change in my firebase database.

Comment: @rigotre, you said that activity is resumed after everything is done? It means that the activity is only resumed, after the firebase operation is completed?

Comment: Is your firebase work blocking the IntentService? I am assuming they both are running in different threads and IntentService shuts down before firebase is done doing it's job to send a broadcast

Comment: It's too little code to understand what's happening

Comment: Are the activity and the service in the same process? IOW, have you used `android:process` in the manifest to move one of them to a different process?

Comment: @SheikhAman Actually I think you're right. I know firebase operations are asynchronous so it may not be reaching that point in the code before the IntentService is done.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have not. I wasn't aware this was necessary

Comment: @tingyik90 After reading other comments, I don't think the firebase operation completes before the IntentService ends. This may be why the operation to my database is successful (runs on different thread) but my broadcast doesn't send (because I'm already back to my Activity). But wouldn't it still send if that code is running on a different thread?

Comment: "I wasn't aware this was necessary" -- it's *not* necessary. However, had you done it, it would have explained your problem, as `LocalBroadcastManager` does not work across processes.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see what you're saying, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @rigotre, firebase does run on a different thread. A few things:
1. Your activity should be in foreground at all times. The intent service should be doing the job in background and then pass the result back to activity once it is done. As you said "because I'm already back to my Activity", is the activity terminated or something?
2. Intent service is destroyed once it executes `setValue` of firebase. It will not wait for the `onCompleteListener` to trigger, as it already reached the end of code.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to move the method `sendResult` directly into the `onCompleteListener`.

Comment: @tingyik90 Isn't that the same as what I have now? `IntentService` will be destroyed regardless of `onCompleteListener` being triggered so the result won't be sent. I need a way to wait until the `onCompleteListener` is triggered before `IntentService` ends

Comment: Based on my experience, onCompleteListener is called, but the method sendResult is unable to be executed since it is a method of Intent service. To confirm, just put a log that triggers under onCompleteListener directly and another one in sendResult. The first one should log something while the second one might not trigger at all. So moving the sendResult method into onCompleteListener should work as intended.

Comment: Furthermore, if you need to keep the service alive, you need to use `Service` class instead of Intent Service. Then stop the service once onCompleteListener triggers.